# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Когда ...(,) или когда..., тогда...."?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Но когда она осознаётся в Сердце, или когда она захватывает твоё Сердце, тогда она захватывает тебя...

Comment: Сложносочинённое предложение требует отделения частей запятыми или другими знаками, мне думается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Но когда она осознаётся в Сердце или когда она захватывает твоё Сердце, тогда она захватывает тебя...

Это однородные придаточные, потому запятая  по правилам не ставится.

Можно предложить более интересный интонационный вариант с авторским тире:

Но когда она осознаётся в Сердце или когда она захватывает твоё Сердце - тогда она захватывает тебя...

Answer (score 0):

Если однородные члены связаны одиночными соединительными или разделительными союзами, то запятая не ставится, как правило. И в данном случае её лучше не ставить. Но и поставленная запятая не будет ошибкой, так как в таком случае союз "или" превратится в противительный и будет соединять сочинительный союз с частью сложноподчинённого предложения.

Comment: Наби, а где в предложении Вы видите сочинительный союз и по какому правилу союз "или" может превращаться в противительный?

Comment: Не понял сути вопроса, уважаемый Серж. Уточните его, прошу Вас. Вы считаете, что союз "или" не может быть противительным или же я не верно понял Вас?

Comment: Да, именно так. Приведите, пожалуйста, хоть какую-н. литературу, где бы говорилось, что союз ''или" может быть противительным.

Comment: Обязательно литературу? Нельзя ограничиться примером, когда союз "или" становится противительным?!
Пример: Все люди должны вести себя скромно, **или** же ты особый?

Comment: Я могу согласиться с Вами, что в предложении "Но когда она осознаётся в Сердце или когда она захватывает твоё Сердце, тогда она захватывает тебя" само "но" стоящее в начале уже играет роль противительного союза, а потому разделением посредством запятой трудно превратить союз "или" в противительный. Пример был не совсем удачным - точнее пояснение - верно. Однако немного переиначив предложение можно превратить союз "или" в противительный. Например: Она захватывает тебя, когда она осознаётся в сердце твоём, или когда она захватывает твоё сердце!"...

Comment: ...Я понимаю Вас, Вы видимо закоренелый книжник и буквалист (с), и поскольку нигде не говорится о союзе "или" как о противительном, то Вы и не можете принять его таковым ни в коем разе, нет у него никакого права "превращаться в противительный". Но он им становится не по праву, а по факту :)
**Короче говоря я согласен с Вашим замечанием по части того, что в том примере, что я предлагал в своём ответе союз "или" не превращается в противительный.**

Comment: Наби, в данном случае союз или имеет значение взаимоисключения, а не противопоставления. Т.е. или предлогает выбор между двумя предметами. Противительный союз ограничивает то, что было сказано в первом предложении и никогда не предполагает никакого выбора.

Comment: Наби, если вы не понимаете значение этих двух союзов, это еще не делает меня, как Вы говорите, "закоренелый книжник и буквалист (с)''. И уж тем более не делает ни при каких обстоятельствах союз "или"  противительным.

Comment: "**Наби, если вы не понимаете значение этих двух союзов, это еще не делает меня, как Вы говорите, "закоренелый книжник и буквалист (с)''. И уж тем более не делает ни при каких обстоятельствах союз "или" противительным**"

================

Дорогой и добрый друг (позвольте назвать Вас себе другом!) Серж. Во-первых, прошу простить меня, если своей шуткой задел Вас.
А затем, прошу сделать мне скидку, как юристу, а не филологу.
_______________________

**Пожалуйста, избегайте развернутых обсуждений в комментариях.**

=================


Замечание принято во внимание и сделаны выводы. Спасибо.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27292/discussion-between---and-).